# Is there a native "file explorer" in Qt that I can use to have the user select path to a specific file?

Tags: c++, c, qt, qtgui, qfiledialog

I have a small application that requires the pathway to a specific file that will be given at run-time by the user. All I need is the path. I image this to be some form of a *file explorer* in which the user may traverse through the directory tree.

Is there a way to do this in Qt, or must I call the native OS implementation (if that is possible). If not in Qt, how can I make use of the local OS implementation?

Comment: Have you looked up documentation of `QFileDialog`? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html

Comment: I did a google search and that did not come up. All I found was a few [open-source](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/QtFileMan?content=126862) programs. Perhaps I was using the wrong keywords. Thank you! In general, is it possible to use the local OS file system API? I've never actually tried this, I am just curious to know if it's possible.

Comment: If you would like to keep your program OS independent, I would suggest use of Qt's file system classes - `QDir`, `QDirIterator`, `QFile,` `QFileInfo`, etc.

Comment: @sherrellbc `QFileDialog` is what you want. It uses native file system; just check R Sahu's link.

Comment: @sherrellbc: you probably looked for file manager rather than file dialog while googling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what [QFileDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QFileDialog.html) is trying to achieve, so I would suggest to use that if it is a widget based application. All you will need to write is something like this:

```
fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
tr("Open Image"), "/home/jana", tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"));
```

This will bring up a dialog for selection that the user can use for navigation.

If you happen to use QML, you could give a try to the [FileDialog component](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html). Then, you would write something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0

FileDialog {
    id: fileDialog
    title: "Please choose a file"
    onAccepted: {
        console.log("You chose: " + fileDialog.fileUrls)
        Qt.quit()
    }
    onRejected: {
        console.log("Canceled")
        Qt.quit()
    }
    Component.onCompleted: visible = true
}
```